# EXCEL: How to copy a row if it contains a certain text to another worksheet without VBA

Tags: excel, filter, rows, criteria

On one worksheet, I have a list of movements, like:

```
01012018  AD  100  printer
01012018  AD  25   papers
01012018  AF  240  Maintenance
01012018  AD  35   xxxx
01012018  AF  85   yyyy
```

And I would like to have aditional worksheets (AD, AF, ...) that only contains the rows by type (the 2nd column).

This without using VBA.

Advance filters works but once, it is not dynamic:
If I add a row in the movements worksheet, like that:

```
02012018  AF  150  Service
```

it does not appear in the "AF" worksheet automatically.

Is it possible without VBA?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes on a small scale. A medium size dataset would require the use of so many Array formulas that it would crash Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If the situation is that there are NO blanks in the data in column B(or column A if better), then you can use a countifs to make it viable:

Data Sheet:

[image]

Create some named formulas like so in the pic below:
The formula in the formula bar is cell A2 of AD sheet. Drag across and down

[image]

Below is the AF sheet with the formula in cell A2. drag across & down.

[image]